# How to select a select box option if a check box is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I am currently running into an issue with selecting a selectbox option if a checkbox is checked. I only have two options in my selectbox with the values of yes and no. If the checkbox is checked, the option with the value of "yes" should be selected. If it is not checked, then "no" will be selected. My code is simply not working and I cannot understand why. Below is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**HTML:**

```
<select id="slctbox">
    <option value="no">No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox"/>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#chkbox").click(function() {
    if($("#chkbox").is(':checked')) {
        $("#slctbox option[value=yes]").prop("selected", true);
    } else {
        $("#slctbox option[value=no]").prop("selected", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: It appears to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/hwkf5/1/

Comment: seems to be working ok for me, are you sure you are referencing jQuery correctly? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Side note, you can reduce that code to `$("#chkbox").click(function () {
    $("#slctbox option[value=yes]").prop("selected", $("#chkbox").is(':checked'));
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to work fine. Have you checked for simple mistakes like forgetting the jquery script tag or to wait for it to load before attaching the handler?

On a side note, I would personally use

```
$('#chkbox').change(function() {
    if($("#chkbox").is(':checked')) {
        $("#slctbox").val("yes");
    } else {
        $("#slctbox").val("no");
    }
});
```

which relies on setting the value rather than searching for an element and setting an attribute.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZLe4/1/

if you're looking for more compact:

```
$('#chkbox').change(function(){
    $('#slctbox').val(this.checked ? 'yes' : 'no');
});
```

(thanks Johan for making it just a little bit shorter)

Comment: Or even `$('#slctbox').val(this.checked ? 'yes' : 'no');`

Comment: Thank you for your help Toast, I appreciate it. I got it to work, I just fat fingered my ID. So, it was not calling the correct checkbox. Also, thanks for the additional compact, more readable code. I was unaware I could write it that simply. You learn something new every day I guess :). Thanks again Toast.